# Removing partial history for a binary file in mixed commits

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a [bitbucket project](https://bitbucket.org/kfsone/tradedangerous) which, in it's early stages, included a binary access database.

Most of the changes to that file that were checked in were data changes; I want to discard the data changes while keeping the DDL changes and the file itself.

I've [gotten as far](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects) as finding a list of all the commits that touch that file, with

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --branches -- TradeDangerous.accdb
```

But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the git chicanery here.

Ideally I want to remove changes to the file from commits in a given range as well as, possibly, remove commits that are only to that file within the range. If you then checkout a commit somewhere within the range you'd get the file as it was at the start of the range.

The coup-de-grace is that I want to be able to push these changes to bitbucket.

The revision range I'm trying to work on right now is 7b9ba..c752fd

When I try

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch TradeDangerous.accdb' -- 7b9ba..c752fd
```

git responds with

```
Which ref do you want to rewrite?
```

At which point I'm stuck.

Comment: Filter Branch doesn't accept SHAs, despite the help saying to pass in a "rev list"'.  You need to pass in a 'ref', like 'master'.  That said, you can't filter-branch a range, any commit that you change you have to change every other commit downstream of it.  For this, it might be easier to interactive rebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing large file from git history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437725/removing-large-file-from-git-history)